# reRender Tab Labels dynamically - RichFaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces, label, tabpanel

I am using RichFaces. One of `<rich:modalPanel>` has `<rich:tabPanel>` with 5 tabs
each tab has label which comes dynamically from properties file. Now this tab has extended data table. When I add or remove data on this table, then I want to change the label with ajax. My table re-renders fine, but I can't re-render the tab label. If I try to re-render the tab, it re-renders the whole tab content except the tab itself where the label is. If I try to re-render the entire tabbed panel, it re-renders everything and changes tab focus as well.

How can I re-render a tab label without re-rendering the entire tabbed panel?

Answer (score 0):

**You need to set selectedTab attribute to the currentTab and reRender the tabPanel**.

Look for click event for tabPanel which will set the current selected tab to the bean and  when ever you reRender the whole panel you can still bein same tab.  If you find any difficulty i can send you the code for setting the current tab.